# Entering string array to a function C++

Tags: c++

So I am entering an array and a number which is the length of the array to a function called "Write" like this :

```
string write (int n, char t[100])
```

To keep it simple i would only like to write the values of the array out whit the help of this function like this:

```
{
    int i;

    for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {
        if (t[i]=='a') {
        printf("%c" , t[i]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In the `int main()`  only thing I did was I used a `scanf` for the `n` variable and gave from 1 to `n` a 'a' string value in the array.And I called the write function `string write(n,t[100]);` Here is the whole "main" :

```
    int main()  
{  
    int i,n;   
    char t[100];  
    scanf("%i" ,&n);  

    for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {
            t[i]='a';
            }
string write (n,t[100]);  
return 0;  
}
```

My question is why wont this simple program run I can enter the value of the `n` but won't print anything out? I must be missing something out whit the declaration's or calling of the function I am new to C++.

Comment: I suggest that you read a basic C++ book. Check the chapter about "functions": how to declare them, how to define them, and how to call them.

Comment: Also arrays in C++ are zero based so `i` should be from `0` to `n-1` not `1` to `n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`string write(n, t[100])` is the prototype of your function (type omitted). If you want to call write, you need to do something like

```
int main()  
{  
    int i,n;   
    char t[100];  
    scanf("%i" ,&n);  

    for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {
            t[i]='a';
            }
write(n,t);  
return 0;  
}
```

Passing `t[100]` to your `write` function will give the 100th element of you string to your function, and that is not what you want to do. To pass the whole string, just use `t`.

Another mistake is that you say write returns a string. But you `return 0` in your code, you want to modify the write prototype to `int write(int n, char t[100]);`

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
string write (n,t[100]);
```

in `main` doesn't call the `write` function - it defines a *variable* named "write" of type `string`, consisting of `n` elements, each having the same value as `t[100]` (which is an error in itself, as that is the 101st element of a 100-element array).
To call the function you should write

```
write(n, t);
```

You really ought to get a decent introductory book on C++.
There are good lists of them here on SO, and you should make it your first exercise to find them.